# Basic File Operations

Tags: powershell

Please refer to my first code in PS, below:
I created a `Test.ps1` file and included the following code:

```
$path = D:\Five-Levels_Deep_Subfolder\Data

$file = A_Very_Long_INI_FileName.ini 

#If $file exists, Delete it: 
if (Test-Path + $path) { Remove-Item $path + $file } 

#Run the following Application: 
& $path + myApplication.exe
```

But, the result tried to terrify me with a number of horrible error messages. As a matter of fact, none of the above lines of code was error-free.

Please bear with a toddler in PS, and help me to make it a great success :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$path = "D:\Five-Levels_Deep_Subfolder\Data"    
$file = "A_Very_Long_INI_FileName.ini"    
$filepath = join-path $path $file    
#If $filepath exists, Delete it:     
if (Test-Path  $filepath) { Remove-Item $filepath}     
#Run the following Application: 
& ($path + "\myApplication.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. Everything goes fine except 
& ($path + "\IllustratorPortable.exe")
The Error message reports that "is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ...... "
Would you kindly look into it again!

Comment: Why not use join-path for the exe, too?

Comment: @jpmc yes is the way, but want  the user know the two way starting from his wrong code.

Comment: I believe it is generally considered back practice to manually concatenate file paths. join-path is more reliable since it deals with trailing and leading directory separators. For example, if `$path` were set to `"D:\Five-Levels_Deep_Subfolder\Data\"`, doing it manually as above would yield `"D:\Five-Levels_Deep_Subfolder\Data\\myApplication.exe"`.